# An adjective meaning "along with" right after "quite"

Tags: single-word-requests

> Jack: Do you remember that situation at "Denver Enterprise Hall"?
>
> Jim: Oh yes! So how was it resolved?
>
> Jack: Well, it turned out that Crawbery was a fake agent. Dina
>   scrapped the whole thing.... You don't seem to be surprised.
>
> Jim: Well, this outcome was kind of predictable and quite **along
>   with** my expectations.

Is there any adjective in English that would have a meaning of "along with" (implying correspondence or similarity to someone's thinking, guessing or expectations) that I could place right after the word "quite" (which means that I could substitute it for the words "along with" in the example above)?

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but I would rephrase "how did it resolve?" to "how was it resolved?". Also there should be a full-stop after your ellipsis (i.e. _four_ dots) and the first sentence is missing a question mark. (Just to be pedantic.)

Comment: @aaamos - Okay, just edited. Thanks for being pedantic :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use "quite in line with".

Answer (score 4):

*Consistent with* might be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Phrases *[coincides](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coincide#English) with* and *[corresponds](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/correspond) to* may substitute for *quite along with*.  Regarding these and previously-suggested phrases, I think most native speakers won't put *quite* in front of *in line with, in tune with*, or *conforming to*, but might use *completely* or *totally* in place of *quite*.  Barrie's *consistent with* and the phrase *in accord with* may often be modified by *quite*, as might the word *per*, although "this outcome was ... quite per my expectations" may sound odd to some.

*Added Note:* Adjective *[quite](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quite)* has several senses:

> • To the greatest extent or degree; completely, entirely
>   • In a fully justified sense; truly, perfectly, actually.
>   • To a moderate extent or degree; somewhat, rather.

That is, it often strongly reinforces rather than slightly weakens a meaning.  Consider terms like *mostly*, *moderately*, or *generally* to indicate substantial but not complete agreement, as illustrated in examples below.  Most of them are quite open to interpretation regarding the extent of matching between outcome and expectation. The last example probably is a good way to reasonably convey a sense of "60% or 70%" agreement.

> • The outcome was mostly in accord with my expectations.
>   • The outcome was along the lines of what I expected.
>   • The outcome was something like what I expected.
>   • The outcome was largely what I expected.
>   • The outcome was two-thirds like I expected.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I really want to have "quite" in there as my point is not that the outcome has almost 100% similarity to my expectations, but rather 60% or 70%, so "totally" and "completely" would be too strong for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You might alter it to *quite what I expected*.

Answer (score 0):

*In tune with* or *conforming to* might work.